# Integration Testing with Authentication

Tags: authentication, integration-testing

I am building a service currently in which the authentication is managed by way of a session token. A user enters their email address, and if their email address is valid they are emailed a token is validated and emailed to them. From that email, they can then click a link to 'log in'.

The problem I have is with my e2e tests, I can test the 'login' function no problems but all other API endpoints then need to use a session token. The only way I can get at the session token is via email, which doesn't seem practical.

The only other thought I have had is using some kind of master token that never expires, but that feels wrong from a security perspective.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem practical to get the token? There are several ways, depending on how it's sent, from stubbing out the mail sender to running a local SMTP server for testing to using a real email recipient with API access to the inbox.

Comment: It's running with an AWS Code Pipeline, so it's hands off as far as giving user access. I could hold SMTP credentials and programatically login to the mailbox and parse out the email body, which I guess would a 'true' test.